# C++ Why is my program throwing an exception?

Tags: c++, string, function, pointers, initializer-list

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to code a function that gets the shortest string from a list, but everytime I run it, visual studio shows an error "Exception thrown: read access violation". Where is the mistake?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const string &shortest_string(initializer_list<string> strings) {
    string *shortest_one = nullptr;
    for (string string : strings) {
        if (shortest_one == nullptr) shortest_one = &string;
        else {
            if (string.size() < shortest_one->size()) shortest_one = &string;
        }
    }
    return *shortest_one;
}

int main() {
    cout << shortest_string({ "hello" , "my", "name", "is", "dan" }) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `string string : ...` creates temporary variable which exists during one cycle of loop and get destroyed on next cycle. And you are taking pointer of it (which points to freed memory)

Comment: `if (shortest_one = nullptr)` - What do you think this does?

Comment: So now that you've asked a second, different question, when are we going to see the real code the exhibits the behavior?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You made variable with name that matches type name (string variable, string type?). Plus there is issue that you return pointer to object with local scope of life. That is UB. Using iterators your function  would  work like this:

```
const string shortest_string(initializer_list<string> strings) {
    if(!strings.size()) return string();
    auto shortest_one = strings.begin();
    for (auto it = shortest_one+1; it < strings.end(); it++   ) 
    {
        shortest_one = (it->size()< shortest_one->size()) ? it : shortest_one;
    }

    return *shortest_one;
}
```

Comment: `it < strings.end()` is a bug. That should really be `it != strings.end()`. `shortest_one+1` is undefined behavior for an empty initializer list.

Comment: @IInspectable oh, in case of empty list I agree, whole function should be short-circuited to return empty, yeah. It is question to architect if the function should crash if given illegal data or generate error, or return empty results. Both `it < strings.end()` and `it != strings.end()` legal for random access iterators, it's not a bug in that case. Technically you can't advance past end, yes. What if the loop must end far before end() ? with linked list iterator you can't do that, but with usual list, vector, etc. you can

Comment: *"Both `it < strings.end()` and `it != strings.end()` legal for random access iterators"* - Good luck the next time you employ that 'rule' when using a `std::deque`.

Answer (score 1):

`if (shortest_one = nullptr)` is not a comparison operation. It is an **assignment**, that sets `shortest_one` to `nullptr`. This operation evaluates to 0,  so the `if` expression is equivalent to `if (0)`, or `if (false)`.

Then in the `else` block, you are using `shortest_one->size()` but `shortest_one` is null...

Try to use `if (shortest_one == nullptr)` instead.

Comment: @Pinwar78: Don't blame the answerer. Ask a real question by providing real code, with an explanation, which line produces the access violation. A call stack would also help.